# Choosing a base where a given digit of a given number appears the most times

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms

Is there an algorithm for choosing a base where a given digit of a given number appears the most times, that works better then trial and error? (see also [this](http://www.smbc-comics.com/comics/20130201.gif))

Comment: If you aren't picky, choosing base 1 or some irrational base will likely work.  I don't think you should invent a term like "oneier" though.  Gerhard "Inventing Words Is Sorta Fun" Paseman, 2013.02.02